# How to vertically align a TextBox based on its content

Tags: wpf

I have a text block I want to vertically align so it appears in the center of a circle. It's a single character, such as 'a', 'y', '?', 'R' or any other valid character. It could have a descender, ascender, be a capital, non alphabetical etc.

With the following code, it appears to align the text block according to the height of a capital letter. So a lower case letter appears too low, and letter with a descender even more so.

[image]
[image]

```
    <Grid Width="32" Background="Green"  Height="32">
        <Ellipse Width="32" Height="32" Stroke="Red" Fill="White"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Character}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="28"/>
    </Grid>
```

Is there a way to get to align vertically based on the text content of the TextBlock, instead of the reserved area of the text that might be in it?

If it is not possible, what other controls / methods are available in WPF to achieve this?

Comment: fix the textbloc size to same as container Width="32" Height="32"  or Width="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path Width"....

Comment: Have you tried this? Because the TextBlock does not have TextAlignment="Centre", the text is not left aligned to the grid. It also does not affect the vertical alignment which is the main query I have.

Answer (score 0):

Landerah in you code only if i set magin for textblock, than i can set text where i want.                                                                                                                                                                        You can also set margin dynamically i.e If character is lower case set magin bit above like test.Margin = new Thickness(0, -2, 0, 0);

```
 <Grid Width="32" Background="Green">
        <Ellipse Width="32" Height="32" Stroke="Red" Fill="White"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,-2,0,0" Text="r" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="28"/>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

A more complete sample that works for me -

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LevelControl}">
                <Viewbox x:Name="Frame">
                    <Grid Margin="2" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="26" Height="26">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="outerEllipse" Fill="{Binding Fill, ElementName=innerEllipse}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Opacity="0.5" />
                        <Ellipse x:Name="innerEllipse" Fill="Gray" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="4" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Label" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="7.948,0,7.698,2.125" />
                    </Grid>
                </Viewbox>

            </ControlTemplate>
```

or try a label `<Label VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ></Label>`